# UITableView Not Scrolling With UISearchBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar

What I want to achieve is a UISearchBar that moves up and covers the UINavBar, and contains a cancel button on the right of it. All goes well, until I use the following line of code:

```
searchDC = [[[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self] autorelease];
```

What ends up happening is the UITableView just won't scroll, but everything else functions as expected. If I remove that line, my nav bar is visible, and the search bar just sits below it, also lacking a cancel button.

Any ideas?

The code for drawing the search bar is:

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"Search";
searchBar = [[[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44.0f)] autorelease];
searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
searchBar.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
searchBar.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
searchBar.delegate = self;
[searchBar becomeFirstResponder];

tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
tableView.tableHeaderView.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 480.f, 44.f);
searchDC = [[[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self] autorelease];
searchDC.searchResultsDataSource = self;
searchDC.searchResultsDelegate = self;
searchDC.searchResultsTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
searchDC.searchResultsTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;

overlayView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 480);
[self.view addSubview:overlayView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:overlayView];
```

Answer (score 1):

Not enough information to answer this. You need to show the UIViewController or UINavigation Controller code (both the .h and .m) where you are setting up the UISearchDisplayController.

EDIT:

You're implementing this totally wrongly. Apple has a great example on how to implement this http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: My apologies, I've fixed the original post

Comment: HTTP 404 The page you’re looking for can’t be found.

Answer (score 1):

From Apple's Documentation,

> `Delegate for the search display controller (delegate), which responds to events such the starting or ending of a search, and the showing or hiding of the search interface.`

Set the `delegate` to your `UITableViewController`

```
 searchDC.delegate = self;
```

Also add the searchDC's `searchBar` to the tableView's headerView

```
 [self.tableView setTableHeaderView:searchDC.searchBar];
```